# Conditional ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Is it possible to conditionally include an ng-click into the dom? Both my desktop view and mobile view share the same template, but I only need the ng-click in the desktop view.

For example, in my desktop view I want something like this:

```
<div class="maincontent" ng-click="clickEvent()">
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

... and in my mobile view I want something like this:

```
<div class="maincontent">
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have some variable in scope which will tell you its [**mobile view or not by checking user agent**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/2435473) and set a flag on basis of that `isMobileView`, and then you can use same template with `ng-click` for both mobile and `desktop` view.

**Markup**

```
<div class="maincontent" ng-click="isMobileView && clickEvent()">
    <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is, the ng-click is still being rendered in the DOM in this case. Because of how this function is being used, the DOM in mobile must be rendered without the ng-click present.

Comment: @JordanMcRae by using the above markup, you will have `ng-click` on mobile, but that will never get execute the function.. I don't understand why you don't want to render `ng-click` while rendering mobile view?

Comment: Basically, clickEvent() is being called on a form to close a datepicker when clicking outside of it on desktop (to fix an IE specific issue). The problem is, in this form is a select dropdown. Because clickEvent() is being called on the form, I can't open the select dropdown because clickEvent() is being fired when it is present in the DOM.